# Why do you need to use Django REST API?

Tags: django, rest, api, django-rest-framework

Why do you need to use Django REST framework to make an API? Can't you just create routes like `/api/createuser` with normal Django and handle all of the backend logic from there as you would normally?

Comment: Technically, yes. However, DRF makes it much simpler out of the box. Why reinvent the wheel if it solves your goals?

Comment: It can be done without DRF. But drf offers a lot out of the box like pagination, versioning and perfectly compliments Django (APIView, APIClient, APIFactory).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**You do not NEED to use Django REST framework to make an API**

But if you are going to make a decent REST API in Django, DRF is a framework on top of Django that helps you building an API with following features:

- Web browseable API, documentation autogeneration
- Generic views auto building from models
- Routers
- Body parsers (auto content-negotiation)
- Validators
- Authentication
- Permissions
- Throttling
- Data auto filtering via get params
- 4 different pagination modes (number/offset/time)
- API Versioning
- Multiple response formats (.xml/.json/etc)
- Exception format to current response format

You are free to reinvent the wheel and/or create a buggy/insecure REST API or you can choose to use a well thought and tested framework to help you build a good REST API.