# Advantages of django rest_framework over AJAX and JsonResponce

Tags: django, ajax, django-rest-framework

I can get data in JSON format, using a view and url by calling an AJAX function from JQuery. Which only needs to create a view and a url to access it. But is rest_framework to do the same thing I need to create serializer, views and a url to do the same. So is it good to use AJAXX in these cases or I need to use rest_framework every time.
Thanks.

Comment: yes you can build rest api with just django but it more tidious to do than just using DRF, you can see the benefits from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50089969/11225821) question and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42618199/11225821)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is not clear, From my understanding you want to know Why Django rest framework instead of JSONResponse?

**JSONResponse**:
    JSONResponse will simply convert your model object to json response. You have restriction in formats and it's not efficient method when u have large dataset.

For more reference refer [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/request-response/#jsonresponse-objects)

**DRF**:

- Browsable API.
- Serialization that supports both ORM and non-ORM data sources.
- You don't need to write all the CRUD methods everytime.

  The main advantage to use DRF is ModelViewset and Serialization. With the use of serializer you can access Related data(Foreign key & Many-to-Many) easily.

From my Opinion, if you have extensive API requirements, you can use the Django rest framework otherwise don't choose that.

Check this reference and decide based on your requirements.

1. https://medium.com/profil-software-blog/10-things-you-need-to-know-to-effectively-use-django-rest-framework-7db7728910e0
2. https://medium.com/crowdbotics/how-to-write-an-api-in-3-lines-of-code-with-django-rest-framework-59b0971edfa4