# Confused about API relevance and Django

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

Im new to web development and trying to learn APIs through Django Rest Framework. I am actually confused about why we actually need to build an API. For example, I've seen tutorials of creating blog APIs, where it returns the posts and its info. Why would we need an API for that? We can simply create regular Django views to do the same. I've heard that APIs only provide the 'data', but I can also obtain data from regular Django. So why would you install a totally new 'sub' framework to do these for you?

Comment: There is absolutely no need. If you have a simple blog, just use Django as intended, with a MVC-framework.

Comment: Please note that this question will probably be closed because it's largely opinion-based. It's a good question to ask though. Always be critical and look at what you actually need. API might be usefull for enormous websites, but for most sites are overkill.

Comment: maybe duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42617913/why-do-you-need-to-use-django-rest-api?rq=1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose you want to build a mobile application that serves some blog posts. have you thought about how you are going to fetch the blog posts from a back-end.
Take the case of instagram, the app fetches images,comments and tags from the django backend in the form of json data and can display relevant data on the application. in short, APIs can be used when the backend and frontend technologies are different and they can communicate through APIs

Answer (score 1):

The biggest reason to use Django REST Framework is because it makes serialization so easy!

see this medium post 
https://medium.com/@BennettGarner/build-your-first-rest-api-with-django-rest-framework-e394e39a482c